# Playground in Swift won't use Firebase

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, cocoapods, swift-playground

As u probably all might know [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) made a Version jump and I am trying to get my setup working with the Xcode Playground.

There is a reference how to implement Firebase in Playground with older versions of Cocoapods and Ruby but that won't really work for me [swift playground for experimenting with firebase](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/FirebasePlayground). Even though Firebase implementation in the Project itself works fine and i can import my Firebase it won't work on a Playground any more.

Does somebody know how to add a working setup with a Playground and Firebase?

Software in use:

- Cocoapods: 2.6.4
- Pod: 1.0
- Xcode: 7.3.1
- Firebase: 3.2.0

Any help or clues here for me?

Answer (score 1):

I created a Framework and then imported into my Playground.  Make sure you properly target the framework in the Podfile:

```
target 'YourApp' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    target 'YourAppFramework' do
    end
end
```

Once you build the framework then import:

```
import AppFramework
import FirebaseCore
```

Most things will work, except for Auth related functions.