# Importing Framework that uses Firebase in Swift Playground ("Missing required module 'Firebase'")

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, swift-playground, ios-frameworks

My iOS app **"FooApp.xcodeproj"** uses a framework named **"FooFramework.xcodeproj"**. Both the app and the framework are located inside a single workspace (**"FooWorkspace.xcworkspace"**). They both also use CocoaPods to manage dependencies. Among other things, my `Podfile` looks like this:

[Link to Podfile](https://gist.github.com/Wilsonator5000/6d2ab0a4d2bedb6d9e7ed8e4e3a2b581)

... and my entire workspace structure looks like this ...

```
FooFramework.xcodeproj
    FooFramework
        (files)
    FooFrameworkTests
        (files)
    Pods
        (pods)
FooApp.xcodeproj
    FooApp
        (files)
    Pods
        (pods)
```

I am able to build **FooFramework**, link it with **FooApp**, and import it in any file in **FooApp** like so:

```
import FooFramework
```

I am also able to run tests in **FooFrameworkTests** by writing in `FooFrameworkTests.swift`:

```
import XCTest
@testable import FooFramework

// (test code)
```

So everything works up to this point. Next, I added a **Swift Playground** to my workspace:

```
Playground.playground
FooFramework.xcodeproj
    ...
FooApp.xcodeproj
    ...
```

Inside the Swift Playground, I import my framework (built for a simulator):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import FooFramework // error
```

And I receive the error ***Missing required module 'Firebase'***. I am also unable to import Firebase itself in the Playground — I receive the error ***No such module 'Firebase'***. Interestingly enough, I *am* able to import `FirebaseCore`, `FirebaseAuth`, etc. without error.

So it looks like I cannot use Firebase inside the Playground, be it by itself or in my own framework. To fix this, I have tried importing both `FooFramework` and `FirebaseCore` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46010010/5569234), but to no avail.

How can I import my Firebase-using framework into my playground? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to fix this by converting `FooFramework` into a local CocoaPod and importing the CocoaPod into the playground.